# Thesis preface section: "Contribution of Authors"

Tags: thesis

Hi I would like to insert a new page in the preface of my thesis. The new page title should be "Contribution of Authors". I could not find any solution to it.

The closest thing I found was to use abstract and rename it to something else. However, doing this I overwrite the current abstract section.

I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}

content...

\end{abstract}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! We would like to see a a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is no 'solution' as is, since this quite unusual, I would say.

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence done. Please look at the modifications made in the text.

Comment: I (and LaTeX) even more miss a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` pair ;-)

Comment: Where should the page appear? Before the title, after the title?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence It worked fine. Thanks. Actually, what I did was to include the code you provided inside the \begin{Acknowledgements} and it worked properly.

Comment: Well, I think this kind of feedback is possible too ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ????

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, what's the matter?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer why did you delete?  Where is the `Achnowledgements` environment coming from? Do you want to answer or close as ... For me, this is a simple placing text on a page, and just overly complicated thinking of the OP.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Because the OP was a non-feedbacker and just grabbed my code ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Isn't that how this systemm is supposed to work?

Comment: @Johannes_B Not giving feedback sucks ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So, vote to close? The question really is unclear to me.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've done so a minute ago

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} %not really needed

\title{Theory about Brontosaurs}

\author{Miss Ann Elk \and Gandalf}


\newcommand{\MyPrefaceTitle}{%
\begin{center}
\Large 
\textbf{Contribution of Authors}
\end{center}


\begin{itemize}
\item Author 1 wrote the title
\item Author 2 wrote the author names
\item Author 3 did nothing but gets all the merits
\end{itemize}

\clearpage
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\MyPrefaceTitle


\begin{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Executive Summary}

content...

\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

[image]