# An Automatic Way to Produce "Author Contribution" Section

Tags: packages, document-classes, programming, automation

### Background

Academic journals and other scholarly publications are beginning to adopt a standardized requirement for Author Contribution sections.  This is a section in which authors are labeled based on what they actually contributed to the manuscript and research.  The merits of such a system are not the subject of this question (For further discussion of this topic, there are several papers available including the seminal call for this change from [McNutt et al.](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2017/05/20/140228.full.pdf)).

As this trend progresses, more codified expectations of the Author Contribution section are being developed.  For examples of this, see the [CRediT Taxonomy](https://www.cell.com/pb/assets/raw/shared/guidelines/CRediT-taxonomy.pdf), the [Elsevier Authorship Statement](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/hkkjot_as.pdf), the [Nature Publishing Group statement](https://www.nature.com/authors/policies/authorship.html).  If you pick your favorite publisher not listed here, I would bet they have a similar such expectation.

### Precedent in LaTeX

While individual journals may have specific formatting requirements, the core of the Author Contributions statement comes down to putting the correct tick boxes next to each authors name.  This is remarkably similar to how authors are labeled with institutional affiliation and contact information.

### The Question

Does there exist a method (package, insert-able code, etc.) to automagically generate an Author Contributions section?

### Similar TeX.SE Questions

[A simple itemized list solution.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232561/thesis-preface-section-contribution-of-authors)

### MWE

This is a meta question, so I don't think the MWE rule applies here.  I can knock something together upon request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many packages developed for this task as it is rather easy to implement the information by hand.
If you still look for some automated way, I would recommend the package `credits` which is only available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Pseudomanifold/latex-credits). If you use Overleaf, you could just download the file `credits.sty` and upload it to Overleaf.

Here a minimal example shamelessly copied from Pseudomanifold for a team of two authors:

```
% load package
\usepackage{credits}

% define authors and their contributions
\credit{Alice}  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
\credit{Bob}    {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}

\begin{document}
  \insertcreditsstatement
\end{document}
```

Downside of this package is that you cannot insert two different CRedIT statements as currently there is no way of specifying the authors that are to be included in the statement.

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to this.  I think this project is great, and I look forward to using it in the future.  May I request that you edit your ``\insertcredits`` line to use ``\insertcreditsstatement`` instead? That would match more correctly with the request for the article-ready "CRediT Taxonomy".